# Hibernate query: Joins and with query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I have two tables. One contains User and company relationship a show below

User_company

```
UserId    CompanyId
  1           2
  2           1
  3           1
  4           2
```

Another table holds user information

```
User

Id    Name    City
1     Peter    LA
2     Harry    SF
3     John     NY
4     Joe      CI
```

How do I make hibernate HQL statement which will give me All the users info which are in company 1?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two entities `User` and `Company`, which should have @OneToMany/@ManyToOne relationship between these two entities using your connecting table `user_company`.

After that you can use below HQL to get user results as you wanted.

```
Query query = em.createQuery("from User user WHERE user.company.id =:companyId");
```